# Setting up VulkanGuide tutorial on Mac

Tags: cmake, sdl, vulkan

I want to follow the [Vulkan Guide](https://vkguide.dev/docs/chapter-0/building_project/) tutorial on my Mac, but I'm having trouble starting. I want to use VSCode and CMake.

Initially I got some problems for the imgui library, so I added these flags in the CMakeList.txt:

```
target_compile_features(vulkan_guide PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_compile_features(imgui PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_compile_features(vkbootstrap PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

Now everything works except SDL2 dependencies. I have the following error now when calling make.

```
.../vulkan-guide/third_party/imgui/imgui_impl_sdl.cpp:50:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
```

I saved the SDL2 framework inside /Library/Frameworks/. Is there something else that needs to be changed in the CMakeLists.txt file to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way to solve this issue. [Here](https://github.com/devnio/vulkan-guide/tree/following-the-tutorial) are the changes required to make the setup work on Mac using VSCode. Read the readme and look at the changes in the various CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Well, it didn't work for me. ImGUI is looking for X11 on macOS.